# No auto-move of applications between workspaces

Tags: unity, workspaces

Is there a way to configure Unity so that it wouldn't move applications between workspaces automatically? This happens a lot (and annoys the hell out of me) when I have many windows open and drag one so that most of it is placed in another workspace.

[Video of the behaviour](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=56EXimPCDE8). Here, the firebug window is placed to another workspace.

Comment: Can you be more specific about when this happens? Are you talking about new windows from applications that have windows already open or windows you had already opened and placed?

Comment: I edited the post to include an example

Comment: I think I have had the same issue you have but its very hard to explain. Just to clarify does your problem occur when you open the workspace switcher? Mine does, it likes to move my audio player window randomly.

Comment: I don't need to open the switcher for it to occur, but it tends to happen only when I bring to front a maximized window

Comment: It's a bug, and as such is off-topic. the solution is to wait for the bugfix to land. Sorry. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to bug#776435 in launchpad:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/776435

There is no fix at this time. Please bug the bug fixers to fix it.

Comment: Please don't bug the bug fixers. Instead, mark yourself as affected in the bug report.

Comment: Sorry, flippant answer... that's really all I meant

Comment: Don't worry, I know you didn't mean it that way. We just need to point out the "I'm affected" feature to new users, because it's not very obvious.